# Average distance from a point to a polygon using MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math

I would like to calculate the average distance from a point to a polygon using MATLAB. The polygon is represented by a sequence of points, such as `P{(0,0),(1,0),(2,0.5),(1,1),(2,2),(0,2),(0,0)}`. Note that the polygon could be convex or nonconvex. To calculate the average distance between point `a(-1,-1)` and polygon `P`, I can use the equation as below

[image: average distance]

I do not know how to implement that using MATLAB. Is there any function I can use?

Comment: Is the average distance not the distance to the centroid? Computing the centroid and a distance to it are both trivial operations.

Comment: @CrisLuengo Assuming we are calculating the average distance between the centroid of a circle to the circle itself, we will get 0 using your approach. So, the approximation error may be relatively large in some circumstances.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can probably use this `intpoly` function from: https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/62278-intpoly-f-x-y

Something like `f = @(x,y) sqrt((x+1).^2 + (y+1).^2)` to throw into `intploy`